# Redirect loop after changing nameserver

Tags: redirect

my site is https://techyuga.com.

Yesterday, I tried to change the nameserver to CloudFlare nameserver. But after that,I am getting infinite redirect loop on my website and I can't even log in to my WordPress dashboard.

However, when I changed the nameserver to my host default nameserver again. It works absolutely fine.

Could anybody help? It's quite urgent.

Note: I have checked .htaccess content, it has no redirect code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on this URL I see a website with a title "GET UNLIMITED TECHNICAL SUPPORT...". the problem is solved ?

Comment: Please note that, it is working fine as i have changed the nameserver to my host nameserver once again. Problem only arise, when i try to transfer the nameserver to CloudFlare. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Did you try this on a different or  incognito browser?

Comment: Yes, i have. It is not a redirect loop browser issue. Please note that, i am only getting redirect loop issue when i change the nameserver to cloudflare. What is likely happening here is that whatever is creating the redirect also has a catch in it to prevent loops when it is improperly set, however this catch isn't triggering when our proxy is in place. we will need to find where this redirect has been created, and eliminate the loop by preventing it from affecting HTTPS requests

Answer (score 1):

Essentially it looks like CloudFlare's Flexible SSL is kicking in. Please one of try the following:

- Enable Full SSL in the CloudFlare Dashboard under the Crypto tab
- If this fails; you'll need to install [the CloudFlare Flexible SSL plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare-flexible-ssl/) to get WordPress to play nicely with Flexible SSL

You can read this CloudFlare help centre article for more info: [How do I fix the infinite redirect loop error after enabling Flexible SSL with WordPress?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203487280--How-do-I-fix-the-infinite-redirect-loop-error-after-enabling-Flexible-SSL-with-WordPress-)

Thanks